# Woocommerce. Have customers add text to product image

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm making a new WordPress/woocommerce site for a company which are going to sell tombstones and I need a plugin that can write that last greeting on the product image (tombstone).

Can anyone recommend a plugin that can manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a woocommerce plugin called [Product Add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/) It costs 
$49.00 for a single licence. Below is a screenshot of how it would look like.

[image: Here is a screenshot]